# MYSQL 2 halves, 1 whole

Tags: mysql

so, I have a database table that holds entries for images, I'm trying to query it to get 20 rows of banners, but some of the banners are full size (take up the whole row) and some are half size (need 2 to take up the whole row), is there some kind of query I can do to acquire 20 rows?

```
i.e. FULL
     HALF HALF
     FULL
     FULL
     FULL
     HALF HALF
etc...
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe the `case` statement within a select clause will help you.

Comment: @Psi You can't use it in `LIMIT`, that requires literal values.

Comment: You may be able to use window functions to keep a running total of the number of rows, then use `HAVING running_total <= 20`

Comment: I don't know how I would go about using the case statement to do it, I mean it's literally, if the row you pick is a half, make sure the next row is a half, but I don't want to order by half/whole because I don't want there to be like 10 rows of halves in a row before getting to a whole

Comment: You could keep it simple. Say that 40% of your images are half size, and you want 20 rows. Then you could select 10 half sized and 15 full sized images. If you didn't spot it, 10 + 15 = 25 and 10 out of 25 is 40%. Then you can interleave them 3 full sized, 2 half sized, 3 full sized, etc.